# Verifying Storm topology processing and Storm UI generating 404 error

Tags: vagrant, puppet, apache-storm

I've setup a Storm development cluster utilizing several sources, such as *Storm Real-time Processing Cookbook*, Setting up Storm on OSX by [P. Taylor Goetz](http://ptgoetz.github.io/blog/2013/11/26/building-storm-on-osx-mavericks/) and of course all of the content from Nathan Marz. Currently I've used Puppet and Vagrant to setup a cluster on a single machine that has VMs for Nimbus, Zookeeper, and two Supervisors. The local machine itself being the master. I can seemingly submit the sample topologies from storm-starter https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter and have them run but I'm having a couple of problems either with running various tools through Storm or verifying that the cluster actually works!

**Questions:**
Whenever I run any of the Storm tools from its bin, such as storm ui or storm logviewer, the console immediately spits out the following and usually hangs:

`Running: java -server -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/Users/jhogan/Development/storm -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/carbonite-1.3.2.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.4.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/clojure-1.4.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/curator-client-1.0.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/guava-13.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/jline-2.11.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/kryo-2.17.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.6.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/meat-locker-0.3.1.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/ring-devel-0.3.11.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.5.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.2.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/lib/zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm:/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/conf -Xmx768m -Dlogfile.name=ui.log -Dlogback.configurationFile=/Users/jhogan/Development/storm/logback/cluster.xml backtype.storm.ui.core`

In this particular case I want to startup the storm ui. The ui logs in storm (from the master machine):

`2014-03-20 12:26:24 o.m.log [INFO] Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2014-03-20 12:26:24 o.m.log [INFO] jetty-6.1.26
2014-03-20 12:26:24 o.m.log [INFO] Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080`

..do not really make sense, as I assume I need to connect to the UI generated from the Nimbus machine:

Vagrantfile:
`boxes = [
  { :name => :nimbus, :ip => '10.200.1.100', :cpus =>2, :memory => 512, :instance => 'm1.small' },
  { :name => :supervisor1, :ip => '10.200.1.101', :cpus =>4, :memory => 1024, :instance => 'm1.medium' },
  { :name => :supervisor2, :ip => '10.200.1.102', :cpus =>4, :memory => 1024, :instance => 'm1.medium' },
  { :name => :zookeeper1, :ip => '10.200.1.201', :cpus =>1, :memory => 1024, :instance => 'm1.small' },
]`

In either situation I get a 404 error for the page.

Running 'storm list':

```
`1941 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.thrift - Connecting to Nimbus at 10.200.1.100:6627
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at backtype.storm.thrift$nimbus_client_and_conn.invoke(thrift.clj:71)
    at backtype.storm.command.list$_main.invoke(list.clj:22)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at backtype.storm.command.list.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
    ... 6 more`
```

Each machine seems to be setup and running correctly and I can ssh into any one of them using Vagrant ssh . I can submit topologies:

```
`storm jar storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology`
```

And have them seemingly run, but I'm not sure how to check if the system is actually running correctly. Where do I check logs on the progress of a topology? Why can't I connect to the storm ui on 10.200.1.100:8080 as specified in the docs?

I'm very new to this system so I apologize if I haven't posted the correct data. Let me know what parts of Puppet, Vagrant, or Storm I need to post to assist in this resolution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you may have port issues. Make sure that nimbus, zookeeper, and the supervisors are all able to talk to each other over the appropriate ports.

As for logs, you can check the worker logs on each supervisor to see what is actually happening.